Finding a collection of random variables satisfying (exactly or numerically) a given set of moment identities
Let $X_p$ for $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a collection random variables that satisfy for all $k>0$, $p\in \mathbb{Z}$:
$$\sum_{p_1+\dots+p_k=p} \mathbb{E}[X_{p_1} \dots X_{p_k}]=\begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if $p=0$},\\
      \frac{1}{p^{2k}} & \text{if $p\neq 0$}.
\end{cases}$$
I am interested in the simulation of such random variables. Is there an example of $X_p$ satisfying this? Is there a reasonable way to simulate the $X_p$ for $|p|<M$, with $M$ an arbitrarily high number?

Is there any reason to believe that these conditions uniquely determine the law of the sequence $X$? Also, are these real or complex-valued?

I have no reason to believe that the solution is unique. The random variables can be complex.

If they are complex-valued, then the solution is definitely not unique: adding an independent sequence of i.i.d. complex Gaussians to any solution $X$ gives another solution. So simulation is pretty much a non-starter unless you can add enough extra conditions to make the solution unique.

I agree with you, but I am interested in the simulation of any such solution. It is completely fine if it is not unique.

A possible extra restriction would be to ask $\sum_{|p|\leq M} \text{Var}(X_p)$ to be minimal.
